# Node.js, WebSocket Location Issue?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I created a server using Node listening on port 8000, localhost.  Verified it's running properly, but I cannot access the WebSocket on the client (Chrome 5).  Tried several implementations from various Git repos, node + websocket, socketIO, articles, etc.  Nothing.

No port conflicts (sudo lsof -i tcp);
Tried server.listen(8000, "*");
Pointed to ws = new WebSocket("ws://:8000/test");
Debian Lenny, Apache22
Node v0.1.98-31-g1c6671a

I'm thinking there may be a conflict with url rewrite. Or possible permissions.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 32-bit and Chrome 5.0.375.125 and found out it is a bug in Chrome. 
Here's how you can test and work around the problem. I used WebSocket with PHP and later Node.JS:

PHP: Download a tutorial file from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/ and extract it in a folder called 'socket' in your webroot. This folder now contains a readme.txt and the folders 'server' and 'client'. Now start the script in the console according to the readme (for me the command was: sudo php -q /var/www/socket/server/startDaemon.php ). It should print 'Start listening on Socket.' . Leave the console window open. Now go to localhost/socket/client/client.php in Chrome. It should say 'Socket Status 0' and if you look in the console you see no new messages (no connection was made).

Now here comes the trick: open a second Chrome tab. Point this tab to the same url: localhost/socket/client/client.php (It also says 'Socket Status 0'). And then close it again. Your original tab should now say 'Socket Status: 1 (open)' and in the console you see a handshake was made. WebSocket now works.

I repeated the same trick as above but this time using Node.JS with the Socket.IO script. The chat example included in Socket.IO-node ( github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node ) had the same issue, hanging at the 'Connecting...' stage. Opening a second tab to the chat box and then closing it again solved the problem and the chat box proceeded to load properly. The Node.JS server confirmed the connection in the console. From then on WebSocket worked fine.