# Nodejs & websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm trying to push data from my browser (Chrome) to a nodejs server and I'm having terrible trouble.

Basically, I've got this code that appears in the browser:

```
<script src="./Socket.IO/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
        io.setPath('./Socket.IO/');

        var socket=new io.Socket('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');

        socket.on('connect',function(){
                alert('connect');       
        });
        socket.on('message',function(msg){
                alert('message'+msg);
        });
        socket.on('close',function(){
                alert('close');
        });
        socket.on('disconnect',function(){
                alert('disconnect');
        });
        socket.connect();

</script>
```

The only alert that's appearing is the 'close' alert.

Here is my server code:

```
var http=require('http');
var io=require('./Socket.IO-node');

var server=http.createServer(function(req, res){
    // your normal server code
    res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.writeBody('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
    res.finish();
});

var socket=io.listen(server,{transports:websocket,port:8080});

socket.on('connection',function(client){
        console.log('connection');
});
```

You can see I'm trying to log the connections to the console, but nothing ever shows up. I've been googling and trying to work through the Socket.IO examples at http://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node and nothing seems to be working for me...

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Edit:
Hi,

I've got the following server code now:

```
var http=require('http');
var io=require('./Socket.IO-node');

var server=http.createServer(function(req, res){
        //your normal server code
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('Hello world');
        res.end();
});

server.listen(8124);
server=io.listen(server);
server.on('connection', function(client){
        console.log('EOH connected');
        sys.log('EOH connected');
});
server.on('clientConnect',function(client){
        console.log('EOH connected');
        sys.log('EOH connected');
});
server.on('clientDisconnect',function(client){
        console.log('EOH disconnected');
        sys.log('EOH disconnected');
});
```

And the following client code:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
io.setPath('./Socket.IO/');
socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {'port': 8124});
socket.connect();
socket.send('xxx');
}
</script>
```

When I load the client code at localhost:8124, I'd expect some sort of 'clientConnect' events to be fired. I'm also sending data on the socket object and there's nothing appearing on the server... Totally stumped. Looking at using node-websocket-server now (http://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server).

Solution: git clone git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO.git --recursive

Use --recursive flag. Doh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Chrome issue: [Node.js, WebSocket Location Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127864/node-js-websocket-location-issue/3443892#3443892)

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me:

```
var server = http.createServer(...);    

server.listen(8124);
server = io.listen(server);
server.on('connection', function(client){
    sys.log('client connected');
});
```

and then on client:

```
io.setPath('/media/js/Socket.IO/');
socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {'port': 8124});
socket.connect();
```

Maybe the explicit port parameter will help in your case?

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I tried the code you gave and I'm not getting any messages on the server-side console ;(

Comment: Do your node instance have enough rights to open the port? Maybe this is a reason the examples don't work. You may try

   sudo node server.js

Also, does you hello-world work? Visit http://localhost:8124/ - if there is no 'hello world' then the problem is with server part of your app - with basic node.js deployment. If so try first get it running without Socket.IO. 

Also check the error console in browser: if some other js fails then the connect method may not be executed.

Comment: It is also possible that some files are missing from socket.io. They ARE missing in github downloads now. Try to do the git checkout:

    git clone git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO.git --recursive

instead of downloading zip archive.